# How to use a picture from a plot for the further code

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, neural-network, imread

I tried to use a plot as image for my further code. I load an image in my pretrained model and my output is a tensor variable. In the next step I plot it with `Image(img_hr).show(figsize=(18,15))`. And after this I would like to use the picture from the plot to convert the colors. But the problem is, I cant use the variable `img_hr` because the type is tensor.

My idea was in the third last line to read the plot. The input for `imagehsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_hr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` need to be an array and I dont know how to convert the plot.

Here is the error:

> imagehsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_hr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
> error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'
> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

I am new in python so please forgive me for any bad description or wrong vocabulary. I hope everything is clear otherwise feel free to ask.

Here is the picture of the plot:[image: plot]

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot

```
   from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.callbacks.hooks import *
from fastai.utils.mem import *
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv2
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 



def acc_camvid(input, target):
        target = target.squeeze(1)
        mask = target != void_code
        return (input.argmax(dim=1)[mask]==target[mask]).float().mean()

learn=load_learner(r'C:\pretrained_model')


image= r"C:\image.png"

img = open_image(image); img.shape
_,img_hr,b = learn.predict(img)
Image(img_hr).show(figsize=(18,15))    

#image = cv2.imread(Image(img_hr))

imagehsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_hr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
plt.imshow(fixColor(imagehsv))
```

Comment: have yuo tried to use `img` instead of `img_hr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fastai` works with PIL Image types.
So your variable `img_hr` is an `Image`.

OpenCV uses NumPy `ndarray` types. You need to convert your `Image` to a `ndarray`:

```py
_, img_hr, b = learn.predict(img)
img_hr = np.array(img_hr)

# PIL uses RGB channel order, not BGR like OpenCV default
imagehsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_hr, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# Display your result in HSV color space
cv2.imshow("Image HSV", imagehsv)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what im looking for. But I am still struggeling.
Here is the next error:
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1

Propably I've got the wrong type of `cvtCOLOR`. I've added the picture from the plot in the post. Any idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @lkrss  Can you try to replace `cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV` with `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR` ? Your image might be grayscale. In which case, the conversion won't work.

Comment: Yes I tried it, but you've got error: >unsopported depth of input image:  >'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)